# Referring to my custom BitmapDrawable from android:src in a resource XML

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, android-resources

I have a `FrameLayout` as follows (both android:src attributes refer to .png files in `/res/drawable` folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFrame"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/frame" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivContent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, I need to do some debugging for the second `ImageView` (that referring to `@drawable/content`). For this purpose, I created a Custom BitmapDrawable as follows:

```
public class CustomDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {


    public CustomDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(res, bitmap);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomDrawable(Resources res, InputStream is) {
        super(res, is);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomDrawable(Resources res, String filepath) {
        super(res, filepath);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomDrawable(Resources res) {
        super(res);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG,"CustomDrawable.onBoundsChanged: "+bounds);
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
    }

}
```

Question:

1. How do I specify my `CustomDrawable` in XML (and tell it to use `@drawable/content`)
2. How do I then tell the `ImageView` in the layout XML to point to my `CustomDrawable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it xml file, but you can do in code:

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivContent)).setImageDrawable(new CustomDrawable(...))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was really hoping to do it in XML; but I suppose this will have to do. Will wait to see if I get any better answers before accepting this one :D. BTW, this is how I did it: `drContent = new CustomDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.content));
        ivContent.setImageDrawable(drContent);`